# Hibernate 4 upgrade (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode())

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my application from hibernate 3.4 to 4.1.0 FINAL version and getting the below mentioned error.

I am using spring 3.2 right now. and my pom file looks like the following.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.org.hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate JPA Provider -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.org.hibernate.ejb</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Following is the entity manager and session factory

```
    <bean id="testSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        autowire="byName">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="testDataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>test</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="unit" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="datasource" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">"true"</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Following is the error.

```
[ERROR] [main] 12-09 15:05:55,168 [ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [api-service.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
    at 

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:633)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:288)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at 
[ERROR] [main] 12-09 15:05:55,169 [log] - Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@3a780024{/,file:/Users/Aanchal/avos/platform/src/avos-api/src/main/webapp/}
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [api-service.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:633)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
```

I followed the following link to upgrade the application. Help is appreciated.

Comment: forgot to put the link - http://spring.io/blog/2012/04/06/migrating-to-spring-3-1-and-hibernate-4-1

Answer (score 2):

You're runtime is Java EE 5 (or older) while the code is expecteding Java EE 6. Looking at [Java EE 5's PersistenceUnitInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo.html) there's no such method `getValidationModel()`. You might be able to fix this simply by upgrading runtime to Java EE 6

Answer (score 1):

I was using an 1.0.0 version of javax persistence lib

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>com.springsource.javax.persistence</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

Changing the version fixed it.,

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use **spring-boot-jpa** and **javax.persistence.jpa** which cause dependencies crashed. **Delete javax.persistence.jpa** will be helpful.

Check your dependencies, check whether some dependencies are repetitive.
(mvn dependency tree)
(In Idea click maven tools and click **SHOW DEPENDENCIES**